# How To Move Minus Sign From Right To Left?

Tags: vba, ms-word, digits

I need an MSWord macro to convert these below values :

568.63-
682.3-
12.78-

To

-568.63
-682.3
-12.78

Comment: You need to do a wildcard search.  The search text will be "([0-9.]{1,})(-)( )".  The replacetext will be "\2\1".  More information on wildcard searches here 'https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm'.  Itr would be wise to test the search and replace string interactively in word before implementing the macro.  Good Luck

Comment: This wildcard is not working. I have tested this on the numbers, have you tested it at your end?

Comment: Search text ([0-9.]{1,})(-), Replacetext with \2\1. This works for me.! Thanks

Comment: My bad.  The replace text should have been "\2\1\3" because the last () just contained a space.  If you leave out the space then a range such as 80.9-100.1 would be affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need a macro for this. All you need is a wildcard Find/Replace with:

```
Find = (<[0-9.]@)(-)
Replace = \2\1
```

As a macro, this would become:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "(<[0-9.]@)(-)"
    .Replacement.Text = "\2\1"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

As for the 80.9-100.1 issue identified by @Freeflow, I'd be inclined to replace those hyphens with something other than a normal hyphen (e.g. a non-breaking hyphen). In that case, you might use a macro coded like:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "([0-9])-([0-9])"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1^~\2"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "(<[0-9.]@)(-)"
    .Replacement.Text = "\2\1"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```